# Which linear transformations do not change the column sums?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$, and a linear transformation represented by $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$. I'm interested in the column sums of $X$, which we can write as $$c(X) = \mathbf{1}^\top_n X.$$ Is there a term for the set of matrices $A$ that has the property that $c(X) = c(XA)$? I'm having trouble proving that all orthogonal matrices have this property, so I assume they do not? What about rotation matrices? Or does only the identity matrix $I_d$ have this property?

Interestingly enough, I noticed that if we had instead done a pre-multiplication above, then the set of doubly-stochastic matrices would have preserved column sums. But this does not seem to work with post-multiplications.

Comment: Is $d=n$, so that $XA$ is just the matrix product, or is $d=n^2$ so that $A$ is understood to be a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ to itself?

Comment: Do you want an $A$ that works for all $X$ or do you want a class of $A$s for a particular $X$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin - it is just the matrix product. I edited to fix a typo: X is a n-by-d matrix.

Comment: @Anvit -- I was originally thinking in terms of an $A$ that works for all $X$, but I'm actually interested in both and will accept either as an answer.

Comment: $A$ needs to have your vector $\mathbf 1^\top X$ as a left eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$. So you need to look only at those matrices $X$ with the same column sum vector.